# How to say thanks to somebody if you don't have 50 reputation

Tags: discussion

I found an answer to my problem. I want to say thanks through a comment but I was unable to do so because I do not have enough reputation.

How can I say thanks?

Comment: Vote up his answer

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers: **Please do _not_ add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you".**

Comment: We don't do chit-chat on stackoverflow. Facebook is much better in that... see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/433/158100) for some historic context to that.

Comment: It's the thought that counts.

Comment: Pay it forward. Help someone else out by answering their question.

Comment: In this case, the best way to say thank you to the community is to not clutter it up with useless noise like comments that say "thanks"

Answer (score 9):

Adding a comment that says "thanks" is the least useful thing you can do. This is true whether you can or cannot post comments on the site, quite irrespective of your reputation.

What you should do is:

1. If you find that the answer is of a quality that warrants an upvote, upvote it. However, please don't upvote answers that are bad answers **only** to thank the author for their effort. This is harmful. Less perceptive visitors might try the incorrect answer only to find that it is incorrect, etc. Also mark the helpful answer as accepted if you can accept it and it did solve your problem. (A useful answer is not necessarily one you should mark as accepted but I'm not going go into the details of when you should accept answers. Search Meta if you need.)
2. If you can't do the above, pay it forward. Post your own quality answers. Ask quality questions. Edit. Flag. Etc.

   And I would say that generally the politeness that is most appreciated is taking care of thinking through your posts before posting them, and if you post questions, being responsive to the help you are getting.

Comment: As a side-effect of doing number 2, you will very soon have the reputation to do number 1.

Comment: @Deduplicator And then you have a lot of cleaning up to do...

Comment: @James: Ehm, what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you asked the question, then you can comment and accept the answer.

Otherwise, as you cannot comment (nor upvote prior to 15 rep), you can bookmark the page and return when you can upvote.

But don't comment to say "thanks" unless you have something more specific to add, such as:

> Thanks for this, I especially agree with your approach on XYZ, as this is more secure than ABC as others have suggested

Comments are for useful and constructive *discussions*.

Comment: If others have already suggested something, is it really necessary to repeat it in yet another comment?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Not sure what you mean?

Comment: I was referring to your example comment: "I especially agree with your approach on XYZ, as this is more secure than ABC as others have suggested." Personally, I don't think a comment like this really adds anything. If somebody else has already stated (in comments or in an answer) that XYZ is more secure than ABC, there's no need to add yet another comment saying, "I, too, think XYZ is more secure than ABC." You can just upvote the existing comment if you agree with it. I'm being nit-picky, of course, but I think you could have picked a better example to present to a 1-rep user.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Ah got you now. In that case yes just upvote the comment. I agree with you, but at the same time.. the question is about asking how to say "thanks", so my answer is about why not to just say "thanks", and I could go on forever listing the rules and site etiquette in various given scenarios.